# How the 'NOT' operator(!) works when used with methods in Java?

Tags: java, methods, unary-operator

This is an example of using access modifiers to avoid generating exceptions:

```java
class FailSoftArray {
    private int a[];
    private int errval;
    public int length;

    public FailSoftArray(int size, int errv) {
        a = new int[size];
        errval = errv;
        length = size;
    }

    public int get(int index) {
        if(indexOK(index)) return a[index];
        return errval;
    }

    public boolean put(int index, int val) {
        if(indexOK(index)) {
            a[index] = val;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private boolean indexOK(int index) {
        if(index >= 0 & index < length) return true;
        return false;
    }
}

public class TestMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FailSoftArray333 fs = new FailSoftArray(5, -1);
        int x;

        System.out.println("\nError access message.");
        for(int i = 0; i < (fs.length * 2); i++)
            if(!fs.put(i, i*10))
                System.out.println("Index " + i + " outside the range of the array");

        for(int i =0; i < (fs.length * 2); i++) {
            x = fs.get(i);
            if(x != -1) System.out.print(x + " ");
            else
                System.out.println("Index " + i + " outside the range of the array");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why in this case I have to use the operator (!) for the code to work correctly:

```java
        System.out.println("\nError access message.");
        for(int i = 0; i < (fs.length * 2); i++)
            if(!fs.put(i, i*10))
                System.out.println("Index " + i + " outside the range of the array");
```

When I print it with (!) the results are what you would expect:

```
Error access message..
Index 5 outside the range of the array
Index 6 outside the range of the array
Index 7 outside the range of the array
Index 8 outside the range of the array
Index 9 outside the range of the array
0 10 20 30 40 Index 5 outside the range of the array
Index 6 outside the range of the array
Index 7 outside the range of the array
Index 8 outside the range of the array
Index 9 outside the range of the array
```

Without (!):

```
Error access message..
Index 0 outside the range of the array
Index 1 outside the range of the array
Index 2 outside the range of the array
Index 3 outside the range of the array
Index 4 outside the range of the array
0 10 20 30 40 Index 5 outside the range of the array
Index 6 outside the range of the array
Index 7 outside the range of the array
Index 8 outside the range of the array
Index 9 outside the range of the array
```

Can someone explain to me how exactly the operator (!) works in this case? Why is it needed and how does it affect the method?

Comment: It works the same way as with any other `boolean` value. And your method `put` returns a `boolean`

Comment: `put` returns a boolean. If the index is not ok (based on `indexOK`), the method returns false. In those cases, `if(!fs.put(...))` evaluates to `if(!false)`, which is the same as `if(true)`, thus executing the `System.out.println` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `put` function of `FailSoftArray` returns a `boolean` value `true`/`false` whether it was able to successfully `put` the new value `val` at index `index` within array `a`

The `!` signifies a logical `NOT`

By using `if(!fs.put(i, i*10))`, you are effectively telling the compiler

```
if(put was NOT able to place i*10 at index i)
    System.out.println("Index " + i + " outside the range of the array");
```

Leaving the `!` out would be like saying

```
if(put succeeded)
    //Print error
```

which is obviously not intended